# What SockJs client url to use when serving UI on webpack-dev-server?

Tags: java, spring, websocket

I have the following code on the client side:

```
var sock = new SockJS('http://localhost:8443/quote-socket');
const stompClient = Stomp.over(sock);//connect using your client
stompClient.connect({}, onConnected, onError);
function onConnected() {
  stompClient.subscribe('/topic/prices', payload => {
    console.log('DATA COMING!');
    console.log(payload);
  });
  stompClient.send("ws/quote/FB",
      {},
      JSON.stringify({})
  );
}
function onError(error) {
  console.log('there is an error');
  console.log(error);
}
```

And this is the Spring boot (i.e. server) side:

```
@Override
@MessageMapping("/quote/{symbol}")
@SendTo("/topic/prices")
public String getSingleQuote(@DestinationVariable("symbol") String symbol, HttpServletResponse response) {
    return "Hello";
}
```

And this is the web socket configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/ws");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/quote-socket").setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:8080").withSockJS();
    }

}
```

I can see the following logs in the browser's console:

```
Opening Web Socket...

Web Socket Opened...

>>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.0,1.1,1.2
heart-beat:10000,10000
Received data

<<< CONNECTED
heart-beat:0,0
version:1.2
content-length:0

connected to server undefined

>>> SUBSCRIBE
id:sub-0
destination:/topic/prices

>>> SEND
destination:ws/quote/FB
content-length:2
```

But the controller method doesn't get called, and I don't see the payload on the browser side. What is the problem here?

**Update 1**
I found out that it have to use `SockJs` like this:

```
var sock = new SockJS('api/quote-socket');
```

But during development I run the UI dev server (webpack-dev-server) under a different port, which means I need to use `ws` protocol, and as SockJS doesn't support it I have to use `StopJS.client`:

```
var url = "ws://localhost:8443/api/quote-socket";
var stompClient = Stomp.client(url);
```

Is there a way to use `ws` on SockJs? How should we with different UI server port during development, which seems to be pretty common.